# How to trigger Azure Devops release pipeline using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to trigger Azure DevOps release pipeline using jquery with ajax but I am getting Internal server error in console log.

Below is my code.

Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Ajax Api call by jQuery</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
      var vstsAuthHeader = { "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("" + ":" + "jmmkdq6p5bndf7jygkepdsh5zzpvzobhhsivvqf2fpafrgur5quq") }
 var password="jmmkdq6p5bndf7jygkepdsh5zzpvzobhhsivvqf2fpafrgur5quq"
        $.ajax({
          url: "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=6.0-preview.8",
          headers: {
              "Authorization": vstsAuthHeader
            },
            data: { 
                "definition" : {
                      "id" : 13
                },
                "variables" : {
                "var1" : "contosonew",
                "rgname"   : "test",
                "location" : "eastus" 
                },
            },
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
         
          
          success: function (data) {
               alert('Success !');
               console.log(data)                
            },
            async: false,
           error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

`THIS`

```
var vstsAuthHeader = { "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("" + ":" + "jmmkdq6p5bndf7jygkepdsh5zzpvzobhhsivvqf2fpafrgur5quq") }
```

`TO`

```
var vstsAuthHeader =  "Basic " + btoa("" + ":" + "jmmkdq6p5bndf7jygkepdsh5zzpvzobhhsivvqf2fpafrgur5quq")
```

---

`This`

```
data: { 
"definition" : {
     "id" : 13
  }
...}
```

`To`

```
data: JSON.stringify({
  "definitionId": 13,...})
```